# Private HashMap - Attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I bought an app from Codecanyon 3 years ago. Now app is a no more active update. So I decided to update SDK version 30 to 32 for the latest device update.
But an issue arises on 3 files. Please pardon me for my java skills.

An error was like this.

> error: getParams() in ManageProfile cannot override getParams() in ContextWrapper
> private HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
>
> attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

ManageProfile.java

```
private HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
    if (!ProjectUtils.isEditTextFilled(binding.cetName))
    params.put(Consts.NAME,ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(binding.cetName));
    else
        Toast.makeText(mContext,R.string.addname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    params.put(Consts.NAME,ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(binding.cetName));
    params.put(Consts.MOBILE,ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(binding.cetNumber));
    params.put(Consts.COUNTRY_CODE,"91");
    params.put(Consts.DEVICE_TYPE,"Android");
    params.put(Consts.DEVICE_TOKEN, Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));


    return params;
}
```

SchedulepickDate.java

```
private HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
    hashMap.put(Consts.PICKUP_DATE, ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(binding.ctvPickupDate));
    hashMap.put(Consts.PICKUP_TIME,  ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(binding.ctvPickupTime));
    hashMap.put(Consts.DELIVERY_DATE,  ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(binding.ctvDeliveryDate));
    hashMap.put(Consts.DELIVERY_TIME,  ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(binding.ctvDeliveryTime));

    return hashMap;
}
```

SchedulePickup.java

```
private HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(Consts.SHIPPING_ADDRESS, address);
    params.put(Consts.LATITUDE, String.valueOf(lats));
    if (landmark.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        params.put(Consts.LANDMARK, "");
    } else {
        params.put(Consts.LANDMARK, landmark);
    }
    params.put(Consts.LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(longs));

    return params;
}
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.in"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
ext {
    permissionsDispatcherVersion = '2.2.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:${permissionsDispatcherVersion}"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    annotationProcessor "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:${permissionsDispatcherVersion}"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'

    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'


    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.11.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.4'
    implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bigstark:animated-ratingbar:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mahimrocky:TagView:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.3.8'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.2.2'
    implementation("com.schibstedspain.android:leku:5.0.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        exclude module: "play-services-places"
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'


    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.9' //for Razorpay
}
```

I tried to make these function public using override method but not works for me, I was expecting to make these function work properly

Comment: You can't override private methods.

Answer (score -1):

`android.content.ContextWrapper` has gained [a method called `getParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper#getParams()) in API level 31.

Apparently you somehow extend that class and added your own (private) method called `getParams()` to it.

Now that the base class has changed, this no longer works.

The simple fix is to rename your method to some other name so as not to clash with the one added in the base class. This of course also means you need to change all code that *calls* that method, or it will try to call the new one from `ContextWrapper` and become confused that it has a different return type (which at least will make this a compile time error, so it's hard to miss).